# Patterns of no formula.

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

How do I find the next number if the given pattern is
$$1,2,3,2,3,4,1,2,6,23,14,19,64,69,12,78,152,93,108,?$$
(Find the question mark)

Comment: If there is no pattern you can put any number since it preserve the
the structure

Comment: Fit a polynomial to it that satisfies $(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),...,(18,93),(19,108)$. Then plug in $20$ and BOOM! This works for any "pattern"!

Comment: I think no need for downvote, it is a valid question.

Comment: Is this an exercise or this sequence arises from a mathematical  / physical / cryptographic problem? In the first case, there is really no fixed answer but some random wild guesses.

Comment: One way to find the polynomial (as AJ Stas has suggested): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation

Comment: So is there any definitive solution to this one, or is it just some made-up sequence of random numbers?
On a side note http://oeis.org/ is a great resource for integer sequences.

Comment: The question mark is at the end.

Comment: Some discussion about the questions of this type on menta: [Number-guessing, sum of all natural numbers and hot trend questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12807/number-guessing-sum-of-all-natural-numbers-and-hot-trend-questions) (and perhaps also some posts which are linked there).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $p(n)$ be the $n$th term in the sequence.  Clearly, this sequence follows the formula:

$$\begin{align}
p(x) &= \frac{600631 x^{19}}{121645100408832000}-\frac{791723 x^{18}}{800296713216000}+\frac{196988587 x^{17}}{2134124568576000}\\
&-\frac{41785811 x^{16}}{7846046208000}+\frac{8219611 x^{15}}{38626689024}-\frac{49026370303 x^{14}}{7846046208000}+\frac{26296057821373 x^{13}}{188305108992000}\\
&-\frac{1098593289863 x^{12}}{452656512000}+\frac{320897391017407 x^{11}}{9656672256000}-\frac{39606777445183 x^{10}}{109734912000}\\
&+\frac{30088961291838131 x^9}{9656672256000}-\frac{(12871880314235441 x^8)}{603542016000}+\frac{(5410873671286319827 x^7)}{47076277248000}-\frac{(708875674839982733 x^6)}{1471133664000}+\frac{4033947669590964373 x^5)}{2615348736000}-\frac{(599274486262658993 x^4)}{163459296000}
\\&\frac{+(49104110859304547 x^3)}{7916832000}-\frac{(2153634755170519 x^2)}{308756448}+\frac{(3188726258687 x)}{692835}-1320490
\end{align}$$

Thus, $p(20)=42$.

**Ok, so that was a joke.**  However, this illustrates an important point--you can find some formula for $p(n)$ such that $p(20)$ is *any* value you wish.  Without other context or information, coming up with the $20$th term in this sequence is not a well-defined question.

Comment: That's brilliant!

Comment: I thought there wouldn't be a formula to that cause the number looks rubbish.But this is a real question where can be solved

Comment: This cannot be the way to get the answer because the formula has more than 42 characters. +1 anyways because we all bow down before the answer "42".

Comment: Another way would be to use a Fourier interpolation and get another value. Mathematica with its default Hermite interpolation gives the result of 404.

Comment: @ministic2001 I am sure that it *is* a real question, but I am saying that the problem is not solvable as-is.  We need context in order to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: @anortonOh it is just given like this.This is like 1,4,8,13,19,26,? Then the patter would be +3,+4,+5 so the ? Would be 34.This is how less information we are given

Comment: @anorton srry if I tag you twice,cause I accidentally tagged anortonOh